# Using bibentry and section together

Tags: sectioning, cross-referencing, back-referencing, bibentry

I am using Latex for my annotated bibliography. In this document, I currently have a section* like this:

```
\section*{\bibentry{Li2010}}
blah blah blah

\section*{\bibentry{Andrews2012}}
blah blah blah
```

This generates a list of sections with the citation as the section heading. What I want to do is reference different section. So, I want to add a reference using \cite{sec:Li2012} to reference to that section. Since, I cannot label section* I converted to section instead.

So, something like this

```
\section{\bibentry{Li2010}}
\label{sec:Li2010}
blah blah blah

\section{\bibentry{Andrews2012}}
\label{sec:Andrews2012}
blah blah blah \ref{sec:Li2010}
```

This gives me an error undefined control sequence `\section\bibentry{Li2010}`. As I understand, it is caused by the bibentry code because, it works fine, if I actually type some normal string in the section heading.

What I want in the end is to have each bibentry labelled as a heading (using section or anything else) and then be able to reference them? How can I do this?

Here is the complete document template

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{natbib,bibentry}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{refcheck}
\usepackage{color}

\bibliographystyle{plain}

\title{Annotated Bibliography}

\titleformat*{\section}{\normalsize\bfseries}


\date{}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
%\tableofcontents
\nobibliography{main}

\bibentry{\bibentry{Andrews2012}}
blah blah blah

\section*{\bibentry{Li2010}}
blah blah blah


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing `\protect`:

```
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@article{uthor,
 author={A. Uthor},
 title={Title},
 journal={Journal},
 year=2015,
 pages={1-10},
}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{natbib,bibentry}
\usepackage{titlesec}
%\usepackage{refcheck}
\usepackage{color}

\bibliographystyle{plain}

\author{Me}
\title{Annotated Bibliography}

\titleformat*{\section}{\normalsize\bfseries}


\date{}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\nobibliography{\jobname}

\tableofcontents

\section{\protect\bibentry{uthor}}
blah blah blah

\end{document}
```

[image]